# Given Arguments is less than Taken Arguments

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from site1.models import Flower
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def home(request):
    x = Flower.objects.all()
    y = Paginator(x, 12)
    pagex = y.page(1)
    flowers = list(reversed(pagex.object_list))
    c = []
    for a in range(3):
        c.append(a)

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'s_list': flowers, 'links': c})


def home2(request, page):
    x = Flower.objects.all()
    y = Paginator(x, 12)
    pagex = y.page(page)
    flowers = list(reversed(pagex.object_list))
    c = []
    page = int(page)
    if page == 1:
        for a in range(1, 4):
            c.append(a)
    elif page == 2:
        for a in range(1, 5):
            c.append(a)
    elif page == y.num_pages - 2:
        for a in range(page - 2, page + 2):
            c.append(a)
    elif page == y.num_pages - 1:
        for a in range(page - 2, page + 1):
            c.append(a)
    elif page == y.num_pages:
        for a in range(page - 2, page):
            c.append(a)
    else:
        for a in range(page - 2, page + 2):
            c.append(a)

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'s_list': flowers, 'links': c})

def type(request, type, page):
    x = Flower.objects.all().filter(tip=type)
    y = Paginator(x, 12)
    pagex = y.page(page)
    flowers = list(reversed(pagex.object_list))
    c = []
    page = int(page)
    if page == 1:
        for a in range(1, 4):
            c.append(a)
    elif page == 2:
        for a in range(1, 5):
            c.append(a)
    elif page == y.num_pages - 2:
        for a in range(page - 2, page + 2):
            c.append(a)
    elif page == y.num_pages - 1:
        for a in range(page - 2, page + 1):
            c.append(a)
    elif page == y.num_pages:
        for a in range(page - 2, page):
            c.append(a)
    else:
        for a in range(page - 2, page + 2):
            c.append(a)

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'s_list': flowers, 'links': c})
```

Here is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'site1.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^(\d+)$', 'site1.views.home2'),
    url(r'^gul/(\d+)$', 'site1.views.type'),
    # url(r'^mysite1/', include('mysite1.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Here is the error

```
TypeError at /gul/1
type() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/gul/1
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: TypeError
```

Exception Value:
type() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 111

Python Executable:  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
    Python Version: 2.7.2

I do not know why this error is occurring ? 
I add url to urls.py
I add link to template home.html

How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `views.py` your `type` view takes exactly 3 arguments:

```
def type(request, type, page):
    ....
```

But in `urls.py`, you allow it to get only 2 arguments:

```
url(r'^gul/(\d+)$', 'site1.views.type'),
```

In this case, `(\d+)` will be taken as the 2nd argument for your view as `type`, since request is the default argument for every function based view.

What you should do is probably reduce the arguments in your view like:

```
def type(request, page):
    ...
```

And assign some name for your argument in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^gul/(?P<page>\d+)$', 'site1.views.type'),
```

`(?P<id>\d+)` will match `\d+` pattern and assign it to `page`.

If you still want to keep 3 arguments in your view, you should change the pattern of the URL:

```
url(r'^gul/(?P<type>\d+)/(?P<page>\d+)$', 'site1.views.type'),
```

So your URL should be something like `/gul/2/1` and in you view, you will get `type` = 2 and `page` = 1.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have 2 parameter, page and type. Why I am reducing to only id ?

Comment: I think your `page` arg is the same as `id` in my example, so you can use `page` only. You don't use `type` in your route, right? That's why you need to reduce it into 1.

Comment: No, link is <li><a href="/gul/1">Güller</a></li>. I have to use.

Comment: Django doesn't care about your HTML, it cares about the URL you request. In this case you are requesting `/gul/1` and `/gul/` is static, so there is only 1 argument that has the value `1`. That value will be sent to the view, that's why you can't have 2 arguments `type` and `page`, it can be `page` only.

Comment: Sorry but I think I did not explain my problem well: I have a link Güller in my main page. It routes to first page of guls mainpage/gul/1. I want to display all of products type gul when I clicked to this link so url have to be /gul/1. How can I change urls.py then ?

Comment: So `gul` is a type now? You can change your url pattern to `url(r'^(?P<type>\w+)/(?P<page>\d+)$', 'site1.views.type')` then

Comment: Yes, It works now but I don't understand why I have to use regular expressions there. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I guess you should read more about it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request. Django uses regex to match a url pattern, so any text like `gul` will be considered as static text.